# Using Files.lines with .map(line -> line.split("multiple delimiters"))

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, filestream

I have an input file with the following format:
Ontario:Brampton:43° 41' N:79° 45' W
Ontario:Toronto:43° 39' N:79° 23' W
Quebec:Montreal:45° 30' N:73° 31' W
...

I have a class named  where the values will go.
example:
Province: Ontario
City: Brampton
LatDegrees: 43
LatMinutes: 41
LatDirection: N
LongDegrees: 79    .... etc

I have already completed a method that parses this out correctly, but i'm trying to learn if this can be done better with Java 8 using Streams, Lambdas.

If I start with the following:

```html
Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
                
                .map(line -> line.split("\\b+")) //this delimits everything
                //.filter(x -> x.startsWith(":"))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Can someone please help me reproduce the following please ?

```html
private void parseLine(String data) {
        int counter1 = 1;                       //1-2 province or city
        int counter2 = 1;                       //1-2 LatitudeDirection,LongitudeDirection
        int counter3 = 1;                       //1-4 LatitudeDegrees,LatitudeMinutes,LongitudeDegrees,LongitudeMinutes

        City city = new City();                 //create City object
        //String read = Arrays.toString(data);    //convert array element to String
        String[] splited = data.split(":");     //set delimiter
        
        for (String part : splited) {
            //System.out.println(part);
            char firstChar = part.charAt(0);    
            if(Character.isDigit(firstChar)){           //if the first char is a digit, then this part needs to be split again 
                String[] splited2 = part.split(" ");    //split second time with space delimiter
                for (String part2: splited2){
                    firstChar = part2.charAt(0);
                    if (Character.isDigit(firstChar)){                              //if the first char is a digit, then needs trimming
                        String parseDigits = part2.substring(0, part2.length()-1);  //trim trailing degrees or radians character
                        switch(counter2++){
                            case 1:
                                city.setLatitudeDegrees(Integer.parseInt(parseDigits));
                                //System.out.println("LatitudeDegrees: " + city.getLatitudeDegrees());
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                city.setLatitudeMinutes(Integer.parseInt(parseDigits));
                                //System.out.println("LatitudeMinutes: " + city.getLatitudeMinutes());
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                city.setLongitudeDegrees(Integer.parseInt(parseDigits));
                                //System.out.println("LongitudeDegrees: " + city.getLongitudeDegrees());
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                city.setLongitudeMinutes(Integer.parseInt(parseDigits));
                                //System.out.println("LongitudeMinutes: " + city.getLongitudeMinutes());
                                counter2 = 1;                       //reset counter2
                                break;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(counter3 == 1){
                            city.setLatitudeDirection(part2.charAt(0));
                            //System.out.println("LatitudeDirection: " + city.getLatitudeDirection());
                            counter3++;                     //increment counter3 to use longitude next
                        }else{
                            city.setLongitudeDirection(part2.charAt(0));
                            //System.out.println("LongitudeDirection: " + city.getLongitudeDirection());
                            counter3 = 1;                   //reset counter 3
                            //System.out.println("Number of cities: " + cities.size());
                            cities.add(city);
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(counter1 == 1){
                    city.setProvince(part);
                    //System.out.println("\nProvince: " + city.getProvince());
                    counter1++;
                }else if(counter1 == 2){
                    city.setCity(part);
                    //System.out.println("City: " + city.getCity());
                    counter1 = 1;                       //reset counter1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There's probably a better solution to my parseLine() method no doubt, but I would really like to condense that as outlined above.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s start with some general notes.

Your sequence `.map(line -> line.split("\\b+")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)` isn’t recommended. These two steps will first create an array before creating another stream wrapping that array. You can skip the array step by using [`splitAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) though this requires you to deal with `Pattern` explicitly instead of hiding it within `String.split`:

```
.flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\b+")::splitAsStream)
```

but note that in this case, splitting into words doesn’t really pay off.

If you want to keep your original `parseLine` method, you can simply do

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
     .forEach(this::parseLine);
```

and you’re done.

---

But seriously, that is not a real solution. To do pattern matching, you should use a library designated to pattern matching, e.g. [the regex package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html). You are using it already, when you do splitting via `split("\\b+")` but that’s far behind from what it can do for you.

Lets define the pattern:

- `(…)` forms a group that allows capturing the matching part so we can extract it for our result
- `[^:]*` specifies a token consisting of arbitrary characters except the colon (`[^:]`) of arbitrary length (`*`)
- `\d+` defines a number (`d` = numeric digit, `+` = one or more)
- `[NS]` and `[WE]` match a single character being either `N` or `S`, or either `W` or `E`, respectively

so the entire pattern you are looking for is

`([^:]*):([^:]*):(\d+)° (\d+)' ([NS]):(\d+)° (\d+)' ([WE])`

and the entire parse routine will be:

```
static Pattern CITY_PATTERN=Pattern.compile(
    "([^:]*):([^:]*):(\\d+)° (\\d+)' ([NS]):(\\d+)° (\\d+)' ([WE])");

static City parseCity(String line) {
    Matcher matcher = CITY_PATTERN.matcher(line);
    if(!matcher.matches())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(line+" doesn't match "+CITY_PATTERN);
    City city=new City();
    city.setProvince(matcher.group(1));
    city.setCity(matcher.group(2));
    city.setLatitudeDegrees(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)));
    city.setLatitudeMinutes(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4)));
    city.setLatitudeDirection(line.charAt(matcher.start(5)));
    city.setLongitudeDegrees(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(6)));
    city.setLongitudeMinutes(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(7)));
    city.setLongitudeDirection(line.charAt(matcher.start(8)));
    return city;
}
```

and I really hope you are calling your hard-to-read method never “condense” anymore…

Using the routine above, a clean `Stream`-based processing solution would look like

```
List<City> cities = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
    .map(ContainingClass::parseCity).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to collect a file into a new list of cities.